# application update no longer needs a password? (elementary OS 5.1.5 Hera

Tags: updates

Just recently ... within the past few weeks ... i have noticed that application update is no longer prompting me for a password.
I have not noticed anything about this on updates. Is this working properly?

Answer (score 0):

This is intended, and you clearly could've checked more thoroughly before posting about it on a support forum.

https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/releases/tag/3.4.0

Comment: sorry ... I was referring to my reading the updates before they are applioed ... must have missed that ... but then that brings up another question ... it would have made it much easier to find this out if one could drill down updates with their descriptions IN AppCenter

Comment: You're right, but my understanding is that appstream doesn't quite work with the elementary PPA's, so updated patch notes don't always get updated in the appcenter for elementary apps.

Comment: And also apologies for my snappy response, but trying to filter through issues that needs actual support gets annoying.

Comment: what I find "strange" is after this question ... I have seen multiple references relating to this "enhancement" on the web ... mind you ... I think it is a good process change ... but my original question was one if this process was/is correct or if it was an issue that had been inadvertently introduced ...

Comment: Yes, I've seen several reddit threads relating to it as well. Something eOS devs could be better at is actually updating their users, and having actual conversations with them instead of being all Apple about it. Honestly, though, I'm not even running eOS anymore. For future reference, however, you can see all the changelogs to everything in regards to eOS on their github in the responding repository. My snappy response was with regards to.. If people actually care, why not just look it up, instead of writing questions about it. If the change doesn't seem intended, make a bug report on github.